# Algebraic characters and quasi-characters of reductive algebraic group over non-archimedean local field

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, local-fields, p-adic-groups

Let $G$ be a reductive algebraic group over $F$, where $F$ is a non-archimedean local field.
Then $G(F)$ is a p-adic group.
Let $\Psi(G)$ be the lattice of algebraic characters.
Let $\Lambda_G$ be the quotient $G/G^1$, where $G^1$ is the subgroup generated by all its compact subgroups.

There will be a natural pairing  $\beta:  \Psi(G)\times \Lambda_G\to \mathbb{Z}$,
i.e.  $(\nu, \bar g):=log_q (|\nu(g)|)$,  where $q$ is the residue number of $F$.

Question 1:     is the image of $\beta=\mathbb{Z}$?

Question 2:  we can choose a basis  $\nu_1,\nu_2,\cdots, \nu_r$ in $\Psi(G)$,
is it true or not, that  $(\omega_1\circ \nu_1 )\cdot (\omega_2\circ \nu_2)\cdots$ give all quasi-characters of $G(F)$,  where $\omega_1,\omega_2,...$ run over all quasi-characters of  $F^\times$?  By definition quasi-character is a homomorphsm from $G(F)$ to $\mathbb{C}^\times$ which factors through an open compact subgroup in $G$.

Please indicate references if there is any.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Doesn't this reduce to a question about tori? Everything in sight factors through the maximal torus quotient of $G$.

Comment: @David:  Let $T_d$ be the quotient $G/[G,G]$, which is a torus.  Then is the map  $\Lambda_G\to \Lambda_{T_d}$ an isomorphism?   Another question I'm not sure is that $T_d(F)=G(F)/[G(F),G(F)]$?

Comment: I feel what you said is correct. Could you give me some reference? There is some rationality question involved which I'm not quite sure about. Thanks.

Comment: There are definitely subtleties when turning isogenies of algebraic groups into maps between $F$-points.  The commutator of $G(F)$ is the image of the group of $F$-points of the simply connected central cover of the derived group.  Already for $G = {\rm{PGL}}_n$ one sees that matters are not so simple (e.g., determinant mod $n$th powers  gives a nontrivial commutative quotient $F^{\times}/(F^{\times})^n$ of ${\rm{PGL}}_n(F)$), so what Loeffler has written is not correct.

Comment: @ user76758: at least for my second question,  $G=PGL_n$ gives  a counter-example. Thanks.